# Converting several Arraylists into an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to put the values of an arraylist into a array, so that I can complete a for-loop project. I have an arraylist with 10 arraylists and each one of the arrays has one or more integer values:              `Arraylist<ArrayList<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<>();`
I used a for-loop to create the 10 other arrays and now I need to put the 10 arraylists into one array that is

```
Integer [] second;
```

I need to put the arraylists into the [] array in the order that they are placed in, I have to do this to complete my project. But for some reason my for-loop used to put each single arraylist into the array will not print them. Any suggestions?
Here is my for-loop used to print the arraylists into the array:

```
for(int i=0; i<lists.siz();i++)
{
   second = lists.get(i).toArray(second);
}
```

Comment: `second` is not initialized. Try `toArray(new Integer[0])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Create temp list
List<Integer> secondList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// add all sublist to temp list
for(ArrayList<Integer> subList : lists)
{
   secondList.addAll(subList);
}
// convert temp list to array
Integer[] second = secondList.toArray(new Integer[secondList.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils;

public class ArrayListToArray {

```
public static Integer[] IncreaseArraySizeByOneElement(Integer[] oldArray){
    int sizeOfOldArray=oldArray.length;
    int newSizeOfArray=sizeOfOldArray+1;
    Integer[] newArray=new Integer[newSizeOfArray];
    for(int x=0;x<sizeOfOldArray;x++){
        newArray[x]=oldArray[x];
    }
    return newArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ListOfIntArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        ArrayList<Integer> ListOfInts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            ListOfInts.add(RandomUtils.nextInt(4800, 7000));
        }
        ListOfIntArray.add(ListOfInts);
    }

    System.out.println("There are 10 ArrayList containing each ArrayList 5 elements "+ListOfIntArray);
    System.out.println("Let's put now above ArrayList of ArrayList into a single Integer[]");

    Integer[] arrayOfMyInts = null;

    for (ArrayList<Integer> ListOfInts : ListOfIntArray) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            if(arrayOfMyInts==null){
                arrayOfMyInts = new Integer[0];
            }
            arrayOfMyInts=ArrayListToArray.IncreaseArraySizeByOneElement(arrayOfMyInts);
            arrayOfMyInts[arrayOfMyInts.length-1]=new Integer(ListOfInts.get(y));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Printing all elements Integer[]");
    for(int x=0;x<arrayOfMyInts.length;x++)
    System.out.println(arrayOfMyInts[x]);   
}
```

}

Comment: Above code shows creating arrayList of ArrayList type Integer and then putting them into single Array of Integer and printing output. I hope this help you